# Cakephp 2 need to generate OCI ERROR

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePhp 2.5, and need to generate an Oracle database OCI Error at an insert using saveAll.

I will capture the number of the ORA error and report to the app admin via email.

I try to include a non-existent column, to generate an ORA-somenumber error, but it did not trigger an OCI Error.

I need to check the database availability, to report the oci error when it occurs.

How can I generate an OCI error ?

My code is :

```
$data_to_save['non_existent_column']['just_to_generate_an_error'];
$this->MyModel->saveAll($data_to_save, array('validate' => 'first', 'deep' => true))
$ociError =  oci_error();
var_dump($ociError)
```

Is there some other way using cakephp 2 to generate an oracle error ?

I am using a web service and need to debug the application using SoapUi.